# How to pass value from Jquery to MVC Controller by calling window.open?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to open the new popup window with having pdf  in it on button click. On the button click , I called the following jquery. Here in Jquery i got the value in "Url". The "Url" contain the following things

ControllerName/ViewPdf/23bbe2eh3be //path of pdf in encoded form.

But I am unable to find out the path in the action in the controller, instead of path i got  null value.
**Now my question is that how can i get the path in my action instead of receiving null?**

Jquery:

```
function ViewPdf( url) {
    var winW = 800;
    var winH = 330;
    var winX = (screen.availWidth - winW) / 2;
    var winY = (screen.availHeight - winH) / 2;
    var features = 'left=' + winX + ',top=' + winY + ',width=' + winW + ',height=' + winH + ',toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars= 1,resizable=1';
    PdfWindow = window.open(url, null, features);
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewPdf(String id)
        {
           //some Code
        }
```

Comment: are you posting the path as url request param? provide the URL string as well

Comment: My actual path is as follows:
/HomeController/ViewPdf/2A7F2B9AC347B50FC6C32C7EE5640A982F3BBA3294E4C3E9E7AE89EA7F4ACD1493912E77EACF15984460D94FEEDE9098D566A93F71CF96A24AE97D29DBD3B533B529F76CDACE4D473811C9321F0DE39314EC954

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define this route

```
routes.MapRoute("ViewPdf", "HomeController/ViewPdf/{path}", new { controller = "HomeController", action = "ViewPdf", path = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And your action:

```
public ActionResult ViewPdf(string path) { //some Code }
```

Or you should define parameter name in query string:

```
/HomeController/ViewPdf?path={your_path_here}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should do it like this

```
//this should call your controller method 
window.location = '@Url.Action(ActionName, controllername)' + JSON.stringify(filename);
```

as you are trying to assign features to your window have a look at these links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp